# How can i change the single marker node icon of the leaflet marker clustering extension?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to use a custom icon for the single value markers of the leaflet marker clustering extension. Changing the default icon of leaflet with the following code snippet doesn't work:

```
var newIcon = L.Icon.Default.extend({
            options: {
                    iconUrl: 'new_icon_location.png' 
            }
         });
```

Marker clustering extension: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for creating an icon in Leaflet, the syntax would be:

```js
var newIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'new_icon_location.png'
});
```

If you want **all** markers to use that icon instead of the default one (i.e. `L.Icon.Default` as you figured out), you should rather override the `icon` option of `L.Marker` class (before you start instantiating markers, of course):

```js
L.Marker.mergeOptions({
    icon: newIcon
});
```

As for changing the default icons used by Leaflet.markercluster plugin, you should use option `iconCreateFunction`:

```js
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
        // create an icon, possibly based on cluster properties.
        return clusterIcon;
    }
});
```

Now I am not exactly sure of what you intend to do when you say "*use a custom icon for the single value markers of the leaflet marker clustering*". I guess you use option `singleMarkerMode` and you would like a specific icon to be applied to "clusters of size 1" (which are in fact normal markers which icon is overriden by Marker Cluster plugin)?

In that case, a simple solution would have been not to use the `singleMarkerMode` option, and instead to make all your individual markers use that specific icon. Possibly through replacing the markers' default icon indeed.

But if for whatever reason you still want to use the `singleMarkerMode` option, then it is not that complicated either. You could do for instance:

```js
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
    singleMarkerMode: true,
    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
        var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
        return childCount === 1 ? iconForSize1 : someOtherIcon;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This was really helpful. Regarding your question, i just wanted to change the blue default icon and not the cluster icons.